# Add a custom plate to new cars in gta

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

So when I made my plate I didn't read the fine print and now only my bifta has a custom plate.  How do I add it to my other cars?

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to go into any **Los Santos Customs** in the car you want the plate on, go to **plates**, pick the colour/style you like and then select the option at the *bottom* of the list to load in your custom plate text.

Alternatively you can do it on the **iFruit app**.
Go into the **Los Santos Customs** section, select the plate in the *top right* that you want, select the car you want it on, then just press *ORDER*. The confirmation should then just say you are ordering your custom plate and that it is free (if you already own that style)